# How to submit a dynamic form in React.js

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I have a dynamically created from in React, and I'd like to be able to submit the values of all the input fields, but I can't add seperate on change handlers for each input elment, as they are created dynamically:

extract from the form js:

```
const FormElements = ({formFields}) => ( <div> {
  formFields.map(formField => ( <FormElement name={formField.name} type={formField.fieldType} />)
    )} </div> );
console.log(formFields);

return (
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          {title} - {id}
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form >
          <FormElements formFields={formFields} />
        <a
          class="btn btn-primary"
          onClick={this.handleSubmitButton}//what do I do with this function?
          href="#">Submit</a>
                    </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

form element js:

```
export default class FormElement extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{this.props.name}">{this.props.name}</label>
        <input type="{this.props.type}}" class="form-control" id="{this.props.name}" placeholder="blah blah" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed this in a quite convoluted, and probably not recommended way, but it works! I've also never seen this done elsewhere...probably for good reason:

Form element:

```
    export default class FormElement extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.props.handleChange(e.target.id, e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for={this.props.id}>{this.props.name}</label>
        <input type="{this.props.type}}" class="form-control" id={this.props.id} value={this.props.value} placeholder="blah blah" onChange={this.onChange}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

form:

```
handleFormElementChange(id, value) {
    console.log("changing: " + id + " = "+ value);

    var frm = this.state.formData;
    var index=-1;
    for(var i=0;i<frm.length;i++) {
      if(frm[i].id==id) {
        index=i;
        break;
      }
    }
    frm[index].value = value;
    this.setState({formData: frm});
  }


const FormElements = ({formFields}) => ( <div> {
      formFields.map(formField => ( <FormElement name={formField.name} key={formField.id} value={formField.value} id={formField.id} type={formField.fieldType} handleChange={this.handleFormElementChange.bind(this)}/>)
    )} </div> );
```

What's happening is the actual full form data is being updated in the form component, and each time a change is made to one of the form elements, it passes it back to the parent form, update's the form's sate and then re-renders the whole form.

The complication here was actually finding the correct form element in the overall form status, by searching through the array for the key, and updating the value.

While I see this working with small forms, I can see how it would start to significantly slow down rendering on large form applications.

Comment: The only problem with this method, is that when the page reloads with the data, it unselects the box you were typing in..

Answer (score 0):

Since they are **controlled inputs** there is not a **react** way to that, and even if there is I would not recommend it, React is all about declarative code.

There are two ways to solve this, one is to use make a property **onChange** on your **FormElement** and pass a function with ids, something like this:

```
<FormElements onChange={(key, value) => this.setState({ [key]: value })
```

The other way is to send give all the not defined props to the input:

```
export default class FormElement extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { name, type, ...other } = this.props
    return (
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{name}">{name}</label>
        <input type="{type}}" class="form-control" {...other} id="{this.props.name}" placeholder="blah blah" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

(the `{ [key]: value }` and `{...other}` is ES6)